# Detecting Lightning User Experience using {!$User.UIThemeDisplayed} and {!$User.UITheme} always returns the Theme3

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have console application that was developed in salesforce classic UI.
Now I want to support this application for salesforce lightning UI in Lightning console app.

there are some scripts that i want to add in my app based on theme selected.
for that I am using, below script, i had written for Lightning Experience.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$User.UITheme == 'Theme4d'}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/support/api/38.0/lightning/opencti_min.js"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js"></script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

and for salesforce classic i had return following script.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$User.UITheme == 'Theme3'}">
       <script src="/support/api/38.0/interaction.js"></script>
       <script src="/support/console/38.0/integration.js"></script>
       <script src="/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js"></script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Issue is that $User.UITheme always retunrs Theme3 for both salesforce classic and salesforce Lightning Experience.

I am i missing any settings or what is wrong in this case ?

Any help or Workaround to this ?

I also tried with UserInfo.getUiTheme( ), it is also giving me Theme3 for both the experience.

currently I am using ap5 domain

```
https://ap5.lightning.force.com/one/one.app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be linked to this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAWGQA4&title=user-uithemedisplayed-always-results-in-theme3-in-cti-even-in-lightning).